# Вывод русского текста в консоли

Tags: c++

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<locale>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    string a, b;
    cout << "Напишите :Привет!" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Напишите :Hello!" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << a << endl << b << endl;
}
```

В консоли вывод абрукадабру
Пробовал менять шрифт->безрезультатно 
Помогите,пожалуйста

Comment: https://ideone.com/PLrAfi все нормально выводится

Comment: setlocale(0, "rus") попробуйте. Работает  на Codeblock

Comment: Нужно,чтобы информацию,которую ввожу в самой консоли,потом выводилась на русский язык без проблем